# How to add an additional Listener to listen to queue with Spring AMQP?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I currently have a `FooListener` that listens to a queue containing `Foo` messages. How do I add another `BarListener` class to listen to the same queue for `Bar` messages?

My RabbitMQ is currently configured like this:

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfig {
    @Bean
    public MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer() {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueues(workQueue());
        container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(fooListener(), new JsonMessageConverter()));
        container.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);
        return container;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no in-built support to route to different listeners according the payload type.

You can write a simple listener wrapper...

```
public void handleMessage(Object payload) {
    if (payload instanceof Foo) {
        this.fooListener.handleMessage((Foo) payload);
    }
    else if (payload instanceof Bar) {
        this.barListener.handleMessage((Bar) payload);
    }
    else {
        // unexpected payload type
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Spring AMQP 1.5 (currently at milestone 1 - 1.5.0.M1) now supports this feature; see [what's new](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/_introduction.html#_class_level_rabbitlistener) and [blog announcement](https://spring.io/blog/2015/05/08/spring-amqp-1-4-5-release-and-1-5-0-m1-available).

Comment: ... or use [Spring Integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html)

Comment: This is now supported; 1.5 will be released later in the summer but you can try the milestone.

Answer (score 1):

Use the same queue to different messages I think is not the best option.

You could have one exchange with two routing keys and different bindings with two queues. The other way is use a wrapper as Gary Russell says but castings don't have good performance and besides this solution is not very "Single responsibility principle".

Regards.